# How to sort a varchar in ascending order in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table inside i have created one column v varchar. inserted values as

```
('A:B')
('Z:A:C:D')
('P:M:N:A')
```

I need output AS

```
('A:B') 
('A:C:D:Z')
('A:M:N:P')
```

IT SHOULD SORT AND PRINT THE VALUES IN ASCENDING ORDER.

```
SELECT v,VALUE
    FROM splittable1, LATERAL STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(splittable1.v,',')
    GROUP BY V,VALUE
    order by VALUE ASC;
```

I HAVE TRIED THIS CODE BUT ITS NOT GIVING THE DESIRED OUTPUT IN ASCENDING ORDER.

Comment: `order by VALUE ASC;` orders rows. You, as I understand, need to sort inside your string first.

Comment: OKAY What i need to alter the code for to sort inside the string? could you help me out in this? i want to run the code in snowflake.

Comment: @Tushar Thank you for the solution! its working correctly as expected.

Comment: I want this query to be inside UDF functions. Can you create one function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg) in snowflake;

> Which Returns the concatenated input values, separated by the
>  string.

We can write the query as :

```
SELECT v, LISTAGG(value, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value ASC) AS sorted_column
FROM splittable1, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(splittable1.v, ':')
GROUP BY v
ORDER BY sorted_column ASC;
```

This shall give you the output as :

```
v             sorted_values
----------------------------
'A:B'         'A:B'
'Z:A:C:D'     'A:C:D:Z'
'P:M:N:A'     'A:M:N:P'
```

Comment: I want this query to be inside UDF functions. Can you create one function for this?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_listagg(v VARIANT)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
    var query = `SELECT v, LISTAGG(value, ':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value ASC) AS sorted_column
                 FROM (SELECT $1:v) splittable1, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(splittable1.v, ':')
                 GROUP BY v
                 ORDER BY sorted_column ASC`;
    
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query});
    var result = stmt.execute();
    
    if (result.next()) {
        return result.getColumnValue("sorted_column");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
$$;

Comment: Please let me know, if above works.

in order to use this UDF function, you must first create the SPLIT_TO_TABLE UDTF in your Snowflake database.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPLIT_TO_TABLE(s VARCHAR, d VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (value VARCHAR)
AS 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(:s, :d))';`

Comment: `If you find something in code block` in the function above;
Add '`' at the start and end of that code block

Comment: the function my_listagg is working. But UDTF Split_To_table is throwing an error like bind variables are not allowed in view and UDF definitions.

Comment: Well, If function works; then that's fine for you,
Right ?
We can neglect `UDTF Split_To_table`

Comment: execute immediate
$$
DECLARE TT string
BEGIN
TT: = 'SELECT ''a+b'''
return TT;
END;
$$; THIS IS NOT WORKING. WE JUST WANT THE OUTPUT IMMEDIATELY IN SNOWFLAKE. ANY IDEA?

Comment: The requirement is if we give one string input as D+A+F we need only output as A+D+F